# Differences in usage between 撮る{とる} and 写す{うつす}、写る｛うつる}?

Tags: word-choice, usage, synonyms

Differences in usage between 撮る{とる} and 写す{うつす}、写る｛うつる} ?

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit and tell us what is not clear to you?

Answer (score 3):

More context would be helpful.

For starters, the last two are action verbs:  写す (transitive "to photograph") and 写る  (intransitive "to be photographed"), so I would suggest looking into the differences between those type of verbs. Quick example:

写真を写す　to take a picture 
この写真はとてもよく写っている. This photo came out very well (read: well photographed).

As for the difference between 撮る and 写す, they both can be used to express the same thing (take a photograph), but unlike 撮る, 写す can be also used in different context (copy, reproduce)

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

撮る → take a photograph
写る → be in a photograph
写す → copy something down

As @user3683045 mentioned, we also use 写す for photographing something.